# How to permanently remove obj directory in Visual Studio

Tags: c#, visual-studio

Do I need an obj directory or I can remove it? When I click delete, it appears immidiately even without building solution.

Comment: VS builds in the background, all the time. Just ignore it.

Comment: What problem does it create the existence of this directory? It is needed by the Visual Studio compiler process and its presence should be inconsequential for your workflow

Comment: Just wanted to make my solution cleaner but indeed its not a big problem

Comment: With [.NET 8](https://github.com/dotnet/core/issues/8135#issuecomment-1483357684) you will be able to configure the `bin/obj` location and move them out of the project folder